# Cant parse string with whitespace correctly using substr and find

Tags: c++, parsing, find, substring, whitespace

When I add whitespace to the csv file I am reading from, for example change "ProgrammingInterviews" to "Programming Interviews" my program crashes with the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'  
  what():  stoi    
Aborted (core dumped)
```

`stoi()` is complaining because it is being fed a string. Printing out each element of the string array directly after populating it shows me that the function ignores the delimiter and stops reading at the whitespace character and thereafter populates each element of the string array with the same string.

From what I understand this is not expected behaviour from either `substr()` or `find()`.

```
fstream finb ("books.csv", ios::in);

// Buffer
char arr[100];
string s;
string delimiter = ",";

while(fins>>arr){

    s=arr;
    int i;

    string data[3];

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        data[i] = s.substr(0, s.find(delimiter));
        cout << "data[" << i << "]: " << data[i] << endl;
        s.erase(0, s.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());
    }
    students.push_back({stoi(data[0]), data[1], data[2], stoi(s)});
}
```

Example of csv with whitespace (not working):

```
111941847,Programming Interviews,NoahSuojanenKindler,0
```

Example of csv without whitespace (working):

```
111941847,ProgrammingInterviews,NoahSuojanenKindler,0
```

Example of string array with whitespace in csv:

```
data[0]: 111941847
data[1]: Programming
data[2]: Programming
s: Programming
```

Example of string array without whitespace in csv:

```
data[0]: 111941847
data[1]: ProgrammingInterviews
data[2]: NoahSuojanenKindler
s: 0
```

Comment: `operator>>` stops at white space, including the overload for `std::string`. Please, have a look at [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) if you want to read whole lines (with white spaces).

Comment: `fins >> arr` only parses to the first whitespace, use `getline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `getline()` instead of `operator>>`.

```
for (string line; getline(finb, line);) {
    int isbn = stoi(line.substr(0, line.find(delimiter)));
    line.erase(0, line.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());

    string bookName = line.substr(0, line.find(delimiter));
    line.erase(0, line.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());

    string bookAuthor = line.substr(0, line.find(delimiter));
    line.erase(0, line.find(delimiter) + delimiter.length());

    int borrowed = stoi(line);

    books.push_back({isbn, bookName, bookAuthor, borrowed});
    i++;
}
```